# Textboxcolumn /gridview in C#.Net

Tags: c#

HI 
  I am doin a project in C#.Net windows application.I need codings to get the data enetered in the textboxcolumn of my gridview .Thank u

Comment: Can you expand on your quesiton?

Comment: This is a Question & Answer site, not a Code-Writing service. Do you have a specific question?

Answer (score 0):

It would be something like this sudo code.

To get the value:

```
string value = gridview.Rows[n].Cells[n].Value.ToString();
```

To set the value:

```
gridview.Rows[n].Cells[n].Value = "Value";
```

Where 1st n equals the rows number and 2nd n equals the column number. Row and Column numbers are 0 based indexes.

Answer (score 0):

On Row data bound you will get tha data of each rows having textbox field.

TextBox txtEndDate= (TextBox)grdTravelDetails.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("txtEndDate");

and the access the textbox value (txtEndDate.text)